# Celery + Azure Service Bus (Broker) = claim is empty or token is invalid

Tags: python, azure, queue, celery, azureservicebus

I am trying to use Azure Service Bus as the broker for my celery app.

I have patched the solution by referring to various sources.
The goal is to use Azure Service Bus as the broker and PostgresSQL as the backend.

I created an Azure Service Bus and copied the credentials for the `RootManageSharedAccessKey` to the celery app.

[image]

Following is the `task.py`

```
from time import sleep
from celery import Celery
from kombu.utils.url import safequote

SAS_policy = safequote("RootManageSharedAccessKey") #SAS Policy
SAS_key = safequote("1234222zUY28tRUtp+A2YoHmDYcABCD") #Primary key from the previous SS
namespace = safequote("bluenode-dev")

app = Celery('tasks', backend='db+postgresql://afsan.gujarati:admin@localhost/local_dev', 
            broker=f'azureservicebus://{SAS_policy}:{SAS_key}=@{namespace}')

@app.task
def divide(x, y):
    sleep(30)
    return x/y
```

When I try to run the Celery app using the following command:

`celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO`

I get the following error

```
[2020-10-09 14:00:32,035: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: AzureHttpError('Unauthorized\n<Error><Code>401</Code><Detail>claim is empty or token is invalid. TrackingId:295f7c76-770e-40cc-8489-e0eb56248b09_G5S1, SystemTracker:bluenode-dev.servicebus.windows.net:$Resources/Queues, Timestamp:2020-10-09T20:00:31</Detail></Error>')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 918, in create_channel
    return self._avail_channels.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/control_client/servicebusservice.py", line 1225, in _perform_request
    resp = self._filter(request)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/control_client/_http/httpclient.py", line 211, in perform_request
    raise HTTPError(status, message, respheaders, respbody)
azure.servicebus.control_client._http.HTTPError: Unauthorized

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 311, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/connection.py", line 21, in start
    c.connection = c.connect()
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 398, in connect
    conn = self.connection_for_read(heartbeat=self.amqheartbeat)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 404, in connection_for_read
    return self.ensure_connected(
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 430, in ensure_connected
    conn = conn.ensure_connection(
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 383, in ensure_connection
    self._ensure_connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 435, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 325, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 866, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 801, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 938, in establish_connection
    self._avail_channels.append(self.create_channel(self))
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 920, in create_channel
    channel = self.Channel(connection)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/azureservicebus.py", line 64, in __init__
    for queue in self.queue_service.list_queues():
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/control_client/servicebusservice.py", line 313, in list_queues
    response = self._perform_request(request)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/control_client/servicebusservice.py", line 1227, in _perform_request
    return _service_bus_error_handler(ex)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/control_client/_serialization.py", line 569, in _service_bus_error_handler
    return _general_error_handler(http_error)
  File "/Users/afsan.gujarati/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/celery-servicebus/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/servicebus/control_client/_common_error.py", line 41, in _general_error_handler
    raise AzureHttpError(message, http_error.status)
azure.common.AzureHttpError: Unauthorized
<Error><Code>401</Code><Detail>claim is empty or token is invalid. TrackingId:295f7c76-770e-40cc-8489-e0eb56248b09_G5S1, SystemTracker:bluenode-dev.servicebus.windows.net:$Resources/Queues, Timestamp:2020-10-09T20:00:31</Detail></Error>
```

I don't see a straight solution for this anywhere. What am I missing?

P.S. I did not create the Queue in Azure Service Bus. I am assuming that celery would create the Queue by itself when the celery app is executed.

P.S.S. I also tried to use the exact same credentials in Python's Service Bus Client and it [seemed to work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues). It feels like a Celery issue, but I am not able to figure out exactly what.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I haven't tried validating your answer. I went ahead with using postgressql as the broker to make my life a little easier for now. However, I will validate your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Azure Service Bus Transport to connect Azure service bus, the URL should be `azureservicebus://{SAS policy name}:{SAS key}@{Service Bus Namespace}`.

For example

1. Get Shared access policies `RootManageSharedAccessKey`

[image]

2. Code

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu.utils.url import safequote


SAS_policy = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"  # SAS Policy
# Primary key from the previous SS
SAS_key = safequote("X/*****qyY=")
namespace = "bowman1012"
app = Celery('tasks', backend='db+postgresql://<>@localhost/<>',
             broker=f'azureservicebus://{SAS_policy}:{SAS_key}@{namespace}')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

[image]

Comment: where does the namespace value come from and what is it that you do differently compared to the question?

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati it is your service bus resource name, you can get from azure portal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Just a small caveat: for me it worked without the `safequote` function. With it I was getting `azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature.`.